# Can someone spot the bug in this program?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Here is the problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/subset-sum-problem-dp-25/

I can't figure out where the code is going wrong

```
arr = [2, 7, 3, 8]
k = 5
n = 4

# initialisation
dp = [[0]*(k+1)]*(n+1)

for x in range(n+1):
    dp[x][0] = 1 

#tabulation 
for i in range(1, n+1): 
    for j in range(1, k+1):  
        if arr[i-1]>j:
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j]
        else:
            dp[i][j] = dp[i-1][j] or dp[i-1][j-arr[i-1]]

for m in range(n+1):
    for n in range(k+1):
        print(dp[m][n], end=" ")
    print()
```

Comment: What is the code intended to do? Do you get an error when you run it?

Comment: In my experience 0 is a bad use for range rather do something like less than 1 rather than 0

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: if you get error then show it in question (not in comments). If you get wrong result then show what you get and show expected result. We have no idea what result you expect. And don't expect that we will run code to see current result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure what the code is doing, but the line

```
dp = [[0]*(k+1)]*(n+1)
```

is definitely wrong, as it is taking `n+1` references to **one** list. See below:

```
>>> k=3
>>> n=3
>>> dp = [[0]*(k+1)]*(n+1)
>>> dp
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> dp[0][0]=1
>>> dp
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: For further clarification, the `dp` initialization should be: `dp = [[0]*(k+1) for _ in range n+1]`